# Gnome trouble on a DisplayLink device in a Linux virtual machine

Tags: gnome, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit. Using the tools provided with VirtualBox, I have added a [DisplayLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink) device to the VM and created the following `xorg.conf` file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "Server Layout"
        Screen  0       "DisplayLinkScreen" 0 0
        Option          "Xinerama" "off"
EndSection

Section "Files"
        ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
        ModulePath      "/usr/local/lib/xorg/modules"
        ModulePath      "/usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/drivers"
EndSection

############### DisplayLink Stuff ###############

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "DisplayLinkDevice"
        driver          "displaylink"
        Option  "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "DisplayLinkMonitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "DisplayLinkScreen"
        Device          "DisplayLinkDevice"
        Monitor         "DisplayLinkMonitor"
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth   16
                Modes   "800x480"
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This works to a small degree - the DisplayLink device turns green, and eventually a purple desktop with my icons appear on it. The actual VBox window is blank. The problem is that:

- the Gnome panel does not load
- a right-click on the desktop has no effect

I tried pressing `Alt+F1` and the console displays in the VBox window. Pressing `Alt+F7` after that does nothing. I have to press `Alt+F8` to get back to the GUI. This leads me to believe that there's an extra display in there somewhere.

I *have* installed Guest Additions if that helps. GDM is set to auto-login to a Gnome session.

---

**Edit:** It seems like the problem is with Gnome / GDM. Applications (e.g. gnome-terminal) display normally. `xev` is reporting that all input events are coming through okay. The panel seems to be partially running but invisible:

```
$ wmctrl -Gl | grep -i panel
0x01200003 -1 0      0     1     1   test-pc Top Expanded Edge Panel
0x01200042 -1 0      0     1     1   test-pc Top Expanded Edge Panel
```

Comment: [See a troubleshooting session in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/777386#777386). My conclusion is that everything is ok on the X front, and Gnome is acting weird.